# How do I insert a VRULE in RRDTool at runtime with a variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm generating a number of graphs successfully with the awesome RRDTool application. However, I'm having some problems with the VRULE option while graphing.

I'm generating the graphs with a Bash script. For now I'm trying to draw a vertical red line at midnight (at UTC+02:00).

The code to get the last 2 midnight times in epoch:

```
NOW=`date +%s`
DAY=86400
ZONE=7200
LDAY=$((NOW/DAY))
MID=$((LDAY*DAY))
SAST=$((MID-ZONE))
YEST=$((SAST-DAY))
```

So if I `echo` either `$SAST` or `$YEST`, it'll give me the epoch time at midnight last night or the day before.

Here's the working snippet for (one of) the graphs:

```
$RRDTOOL graph /var/www/images/graphs/wdata36h.png                      \
--title 'Pi Traffic Count (wlan0)'                                      \
--watermark "Graph Drawn `date`"                                        \
--vertical-label 'Bytes'                                                \
--lower-limit '0'                                                       \
--rigid                                                                 \
--alt-autoscale                                                         \
--units=si                                                              \
--width '700'                                                           \
--height '200'                                                          \
--full-size-mode                                                        \
--start end-36h                                                         \
'DEF:wrx=/usr/local/bin/system/data.rrd:wrx:AVERAGE'                    \
'DEF:wtx=/usr/local/bin/system/data.rrd:wtx:AVERAGE'                    \
'AREA:wtx#0000FFFF:Upload\:'                                            \
'GPRINT:wtx:LAST:\:%8.2lf %s]'                                          \
'STACK:wrx#00CC00FF:Download\:'                                         \
'GPRINT:wrx:LAST:\:%8.2lf %s]'
```

As you can see, the graph spans the last 36 hours which includes 2 midnights. I've tried adding the `$SAST` and `$YEST` variables a few ways, but it keeps reading them as the variable names, not as the variable values.

I've tried adding:

```
'VRULE:$YEST#FF0000' \
'VRULE:$SAST#FF0000' \
```

and

```
'VDEF:yest=$YEST'   \
'VDEF:sast=$SAST'   \
'VRULE:yest#FF0000' \
'VRULE:sast#FF0000' \
```

But the quote marks are causing the variables to be interpreted as variable names.

I really do not want to recreate the `data.rrd` file as it has lots of historic data in it. This means that I'd need to draw those vertical lines in the `graph` stage and not the `update` stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of trial and error (more on this below)

I found that I can't have all the arguments in quotes.

I ended up with this:

```
$RRDTOOL graph /var/www/images/graphs/wdata36h.png                      \
--title 'Pi Traffic Count (wlan0)'                                      \
--watermark "Graph Drawn `date`"                                        \
--vertical-label 'Bytes'                                                \
--lower-limit '0'                                                       \
--rigid                                                                 \
--alt-autoscale                                                         \
--units=si                                                              \
--width '700'                                                           \
--height '200'                                                          \
--full-size-mode                                                        \
--start end-36h                                                         \
'DEF:wrx=/usr/local/bin/system/data.rrd:wrx:AVERAGE'                    \
'DEF:wtx=/usr/local/bin/system/data.rrd:wtx:AVERAGE'                    \
'AREA:wtx#0000FFFF:Upload\:'                                            \
'GPRINT:wtx:LAST:\:%8.2lf %s]'                                          \
'STACK:wrx#00CC00FF:Download\:'                                         \
'GPRINT:wrx:LAST:\:%8.2lf %s]'                                          \
VRULE:$YEST#FF0000                                                      \
VRULE:$SAST#FF0000
```

I tried concatenating the entire `graph` into one variable and then running that variable, but it failed spectacularly as it was removing the single quotes and then believed that any space meant a new command or function resulting in errors like `ERROR: 'T' is not a valid function name` (from the "T" in **--title 'Pi Traffic Count (wlan0)'**).

Then I tried removing all the spaces physically (and with `\`)but still got the same error, this time it was from me generating today's date:

```
--watermark "Graph Drawn `date`"
```

Which happens to be "Thursday".

Hope this helps someone with the same problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

I try to draw vertical line every 6 hour,
it's my  working script

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=`date +%s`
DAY=86400
day6=21600
ZONE=10800
LDAY=$((NOW/DAY))
MID=$((LDAY*DAY))
SAST=$((MID-ZONE))
sa6=$((SAST+day6))
sa12=$((SAST+day6*2))
sa18=$((SAST+day6*3))
#YEST=$((SAST+43200))

bsd="/home/alex112/us/u2"
#dat0=date -u -d $diff" +%-D
rrdtool graph $bsd/temp01.png       \
--watermark "Graph Drawn `date`"   \
 -w 600 -h 220 -v "Temperature"     \
--upper-limit 10 --lower-limit -8   \
  DEF:t11=$bsd/temp.rrd:t1:AVERAGE  \
  DEF:t12=$bsd/temp.rrd:t2:AVERAGE  \
  CDEF:ct11=t11,10,/                \
  CDEF:ct12=t12,10,/                \
  LINE1:ct11#00FF00:"fridge"        \
  LINE1:ct12#0000FF:"stock"         \
  HRULE:0#000000:"Zero Level"      \
  HRULE:8#FF0000:"Max temp"        \
  HRULE:-6#FF0000:"Min Fridge"     \
  VRULE:$SAST#FF0000:   \
  VRULE:$sa6#FF0000:   \
  VRULE:$sa12#FF0000:   \
  VRULE:$sa18#FF0000:"Zero time"
```

Comment: How does this ***answer*** the question?

Comment: This gave me enough information to work out how I needed to implement a VRULE, so it certainly has value as an answer.